# Translation phrases are not been cleaned. What to do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, translate

I have created my app and some graph objects and actions. After finding the correct names for my actions and objects, I have started the translations of my actions in the Localize link.

I was surprised that there was 827 phases to be translated.. That is cause there are phrases related to deleted objects and actions!

So they are not been cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php?app=YOUR_APP_ID

Use the link "Delete and re-import all strings" on the right corner.